# MySQL Stored Procedure does not return output when passing input as a variable using SET syntax

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Thank you for taking the time out to read my question.

I have a simple mySQL stored procedure as below that takes one input parameter and returns one output.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE createOrder (in reqno varchar(20), out out_val varchar(20))

BEGIN
    select custphone
    into out_val
    from request
    where requestnum = reqno;

    insert into test values (reqno, out_val );
END;
```

The stored procedure works when I execute it using the below steps, i.e. it returns the output if I pass the input parameter as a hard-coded string.

```
call createOrder('RQ000434', @out);
select @out;
```

However it returns NULL when I pass the first parameter as a variable, setting its value using the SET syntax:

```
SET @inv = 'RQ000455';
call createOrder(@inv, @out);
select @out;
```

I am new to mySQL and not able to see where I am going wrong. Any suggestion to resolve, is most welcome!
Thank you in advance! Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Folks:

I was able to figure out the problem. After trying out different things, I finally was able to get the stored procedure to work. Here is my solution for those who are looking for an answer if they encounter a similar problem:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE createOrder2 (in reqno varchar(20), out out_val varchar(20))

BEGIN
    SET out_val = (select custphone
    from request
    where requestnum = reqno);

    insert into test values (reqno, out_val );
END;
```

Now to call the Stored Procedure in Workbench,

```
SET @inv = 'RQ000434';
call createOrder2(@inv, @out);
select @out;
```

Thank you for those who took the time to read my question! Regards!